# Javascript in PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf

I am using some the following Javascript in a editable PDF to calculate a percentage of customers
`event.value = this.getField("Customers").value * this.getField("Retention").value / 100.0;`

This works fine!
But I also need to add the percentage of leads to the end value.

`event.value = this.getField("Leads").value * this.getField("conversion").value / 100.0;`

I haven't programmed in years so excuse my novice attempt of...
`event.value = this.getField("Customers").value * this.getField("Retention")+event.value = this.getField("Leads").value * this.getField("conversion").value / 100.0;`

Clearly did not work.
Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Just don't reassign `event.value`:

```js
event.value = this.getField("Customers").value * this.getField("Retention").value / 100 + this.getField("Leads").value * this.getField("conversion").value / 100;
```

Comment: Here is what I got Image attached https://ibb.co/stmtyN4

Comment: @Stacca Are the `Retention` and `conversion` values always a number between 0 and 100?

Comment: Yes sorry I should of mentioned they are a percentage.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have used `event.value` while it's value hasn't been computed .

This raises a problem for you as the event.value needs a prominent value for it to be used as a number .

Just use :

`event.value = this.getField("Customers").value * this.getField("Retention") +  this.getField("Leads").value * this.getField("conversion").value / 100.0;`

Comment: Thank you for highlighting the problem this is helpful

Comment: Happy to help! :)